# maximum number of @id in spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations, hql

i added @id and created auto generate value to my table..I want to know what is the maximum number of id.. i use integer data type for the private variable. 2000 applications reach for a month..How many years can i use this increment without error.

this is my model

```
        package lk.slsi.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "slsnotification")
public class SLSNotification {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(length = 16)
    private Integer snumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String date;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date appPostdate = new Date();

    @Column(length = 8)
    private String cusOffice;

    @Column(length = 1)
    private String cusSerial;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String cusDecNo;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date cusDate;

    @Column(length = 300)
    private String manufacturer;

    @Column(length = 300)
    private String exporterAddress;

    @Column(length = 20,nullable = false)
    private String importerVAT;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String declarantVAT;

    private String declarantDetails;

    private String vessel;

    private String blNo;

    private String loadingPort;

    private String tradingCountry;

    private String countryOrigin;

    private String invoiceNo;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date invoiceDate;

    private Double invoiceValue;

    private String uom;

    private Double totalQty;

    private String marksNumber;


    private String goodsDesc;

    private String purpose;

    private String hsCode;

    private String issuerQltyCert;

    private String qltyCertifacateNo;

    private String slsNo;

    private String invoiceLoc;

    private String blLoc;

    private String packlistLoc;

    private String qcLoc;

    private String otherLoc;

    private String accRep;

    private String accRepLoc;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String status = "PENDING";

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    private String slsiUnit;

    private String importerDetails;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String productDesc;
    private String certRefNo;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date blDate;
    private String loadCountry;

    public Integer getSnumber() {
        return snumber;
    }

    public void setSnumber(Integer snumber) {
        this.snumber = snumber;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getCusOffice() {
        return cusOffice;
    }

    public void setCusOffice(String cusOffice) {
        this.cusOffice = cusOffice;
    }

    public String getCusSerial() {
        return cusSerial;
    }

    public void setCusSerial(String cusSerial) {
        this.cusSerial = cusSerial;
    }

    public String getCusDecNo() {
        return cusDecNo;
    }

    public void setCusDecNo(String cusDecNo) {
        this.cusDecNo = cusDecNo;
    }

    public Date getCusDate() {
        return cusDate;
    }

    public void setCusDate(Date cusDate) {
        this.cusDate = cusDate;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getExporterAddress() {
        return exporterAddress;
    }

    public void setExporterAddress(String exporterAddress) {
        this.exporterAddress = exporterAddress;
    }

    public String getImporterVAT() {
        return importerVAT;
    }

    public void setImporterVAT(String importerVAT) {
        this.importerVAT = importerVAT;
    }

    public String getDeclarantVAT() {
        return declarantVAT;
    }

    public void setDeclarantVAT(String declarantVAT) {
        this.declarantVAT = declarantVAT;
    }

    public String getVessel() {
        return vessel;
    }

    public void setVessel(String vessel) {
        this.vessel = vessel;
    }

    public String getBlNo() {
        return blNo;
    }

    public void setBlNo(String blNo) {
        this.blNo = blNo;
    }

    public String getLoadingPort() {
        return loadingPort;
    }

    public void setLoadingPort(String loadingPort) {
        this.loadingPort = loadingPort;
    }

    public String getTradingCountry() {
        return tradingCountry;
    }

    public void setTradingCountry(String tradingCountry) {
        this.tradingCountry = tradingCountry;
    }

    public String getCountryOrigin() {
        return countryOrigin;
    }

    public void setCountryOrigin(String countryOrigin) {
        this.countryOrigin = countryOrigin;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNo() {
        return invoiceNo;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo) {
        this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }

    public Date getInvoiceDate() {
        return invoiceDate;
    }

    public void setInvoiceDate(Date invoiceDate) {
        this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
    }

    public Double getInvoiceValue() {
        return invoiceValue;
    }

    public void setInvoiceValue(Double invoiceValue) {
        this.invoiceValue = invoiceValue;
    }

    public String getUom() {
        return uom;
    }

    public void setUom(String uom) {
        this.uom = uom;
    }

    public Date getAppPostdate() {
        return appPostdate;
    }

    public void setAppPostdate(Date appPostdate) {
        this.appPostdate = appPostdate;
    }

    public Double getTotalQty() {
        return totalQty;
    }

    public void setTotalQty(Double totalQty) {
        this.totalQty = totalQty;
    }

    public String getMarksNumber() {
        return marksNumber;
    }

    public void setMarksNumber(String marksNumber) {
        this.marksNumber = marksNumber;
    }

    public String getGoodsDesc() {
        return goodsDesc;
    }

    public void setGoodsDesc(String goodsDesc) {
        this.goodsDesc = goodsDesc;
    }

    public String getPurpose() {
        return purpose;
    }

    public void setPurpose(String purpose) {
        this.purpose = purpose;
    }

    public String getHsCode() {
        return hsCode;
    }

    public void setHsCode(String hsCode) {
        this.hsCode = hsCode;
    }

    public String getIssuerQltyCert() {
        return issuerQltyCert;
    }

    public void setIssuerQltyCert(String issuerQltyCert) {
        this.issuerQltyCert = issuerQltyCert;
    }

    public String getQltyCertifacateNo() {
        return qltyCertifacateNo;
    }

    public void setQltyCertifacateNo(String qltyCertifacateNo) {
        this.qltyCertifacateNo = qltyCertifacateNo;
    }

    public String getSlsNo() {
        return slsNo;
    }

    public void setSlsNo(String slsNo) {
        this.slsNo = slsNo;
    }

    public String getInvoiceLoc() {
        return invoiceLoc;
    }

    public void setInvoiceLoc(String invoiceLoc) {
        this.invoiceLoc = invoiceLoc;
    }

    public String getBlLoc() {
        return blLoc;
    }

    public void setBlLoc(String blLoc) {
        this.blLoc = blLoc;
    }

    public String getPacklistLoc() {
        return packlistLoc;
    }

    public void setPacklistLoc(String packlistLoc) {
        this.packlistLoc = packlistLoc;
    }

    public String getQcLoc() {
        return qcLoc;
    }

    public void setQcLoc(String qcLoc) {
        this.qcLoc = qcLoc;
    }

    public String getOtherLoc() {
        return otherLoc;
    }

    public void setOtherLoc(String otherLoc) {
        this.otherLoc = otherLoc;
    }

    public String getAccRep() {
        return accRep;
    }

    public void setAccRep(String accRep) {
        this.accRep = accRep;
    }

    public String getAccRepLoc() {
        return accRepLoc;
    }

    public void setAccRepLoc(String accRepLoc) {
        this.accRepLoc = accRepLoc;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getSlsiUnit() {
        return slsiUnit;
    }

    public void setSlsiUnit(String slsiUnit) {
        this.slsiUnit = slsiUnit;
    }

    public String getImporterDetails() {
        return importerDetails;
    }

    public void setImporterDetails(String importerDetails) {
        this.importerDetails = importerDetails;
    }

    public String getDeclarantDetails() {
        return declarantDetails;
    }

    public void setDeclarantDetails(String declarantDetails) {
        this.declarantDetails = declarantDetails;
    }

    public String getProductDesc() {
        return productDesc;
    }

    public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
        this.productDesc = productDesc;
    }

    public String getCertRefNo() {
        return certRefNo;
    }

    public void setCertRefNo(String certRefNo) {
        this.certRefNo = certRefNo;
    }

    public Date getBlDate() {
        return blDate;
    }

    public void setBlDate(Date blDate) {
        this.blDate = blDate;
    }

    public String getLoadCountry() {
        return loadCountry;
    }

    public void setLoadCountry(String loadCountry) {
        this.loadCountry = loadCountry;
    }
}
```

what is the maximum number can i use without error

Comment: change to type `Long`. more often used. int goes to about 2 billion.

Comment: ok ... is it affect to the @id in hibernate...hibernate will increment upto  2 billion

Comment: no it just works :)

Comment: ah ok sir... i will change it to long